# UITextField empty Bubble for Mac catalyst

Tags: ios, mac-catalyst

Sometimes empty suggestion/bubble appears when editing UITextField in mac catalyst app. Tried turning off corrections and spellchecking, nothing worked. Attached screenshot.
How do I get rid of that?

[image: Empty bubble]

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I have a similar one over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74220070/strange-transparent-view-appears-beneath-textfield-in-mac-catalyst-app

Comment: I didn't find any solutions. I just accepted it as non critical catalyst bug.

Answer (score 2):

```
textField.autocorrectionType = .no
```

This is specifically for non-password textfields. As for password textfields, I haven't looked into which property handles it, but essentially, this is the input suggestion box in macOS. When your textfield is a password field, it will prompt you with suggested saved account password information. However, when there are no suggestions, it will still display an empty list.